# How to get the prediction std using Gaussian Process in Scikit-Learn

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, scikit-learn, gaussian-process, inverse-gaussian-distribution

I'm fitting some data using Gaussian Process (GP) in Scikit-Learn. As I understand, the GP requires to scale both X (input features) and Y (outputs) to standard normal distribution (mean = 0 and std = 1).

I usually use the following code to scale my data:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_scaler = StandardScaler()
X_train_scale = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_train)
Y_train_scale = y_scaler.fit_transform(Y_train)
```

After fitting and prediction, I will use the following code to re-scale data to original scale that human can understand:

```
gp = GaussianProcessRegressor() # kernel was defined specific for each task
gp.fit(X_train_scale, Y_train_scale)
X_test_scale = x_scaler.transform(X_train)
Y_test, std = gp.predict(X_test_scale, return_std=True)
```

I think we can re-scale the Y values using the following line:

```
Y_test_real = y_scaler.inverse_transform(Y_test)
```

**But I don't know what is the right way to re-scale std. And my question is how to re-scale the std if we scaling Y to normal distribution at the beginning?** Actually this value is very important to me because this is the confidence interval. Now, I am using the the following line:

```
std_real = y_scaler.inverse_transform(std)
```

But the std_real calculated by the line above is very large and not reasonable. I'm not sure whether we could just scale Y to [0, 1], rather than scale to normal distribution. Or, when Y is small, such as <10, can we not using scaling on Y?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

the inverse transform of the standard deviation is wrong. Mean and standard variation have to be transformed differently. Here's a brief explanation:

#### Transform

Let's assume random variable $Y$ with mean $\mu_Y$ and variance $\sigma^2_Y.$ The "Scaler" subtracts some constant $a$ and divides the result by a factor $b.$ The transformed variable equals $Z = \frac{Y-a}{b}.$ It has mean
\begin{equation*}
\mu_Z = \mathrm{E}\{Z\} = \frac{\mu_Y-a}{b},
\end{equation*}
and variance
\begin{equation*}\begin{split}
\sigma^2_Z &= \mathrm{E}\{(Z-\mu_Z)^2\}=\mathrm{E}\{Z^2-2Z\mu_Z+\mu^2_Z\}=\mathrm{E}\{Z^2\}-\mu_Z^2\\
&=\frac{1}{b^2}\left(\mathrm{E}\{Y^2-2aY+a^2\} - \left(\mu_Y^2-2a\mu_Y+a^2\right)\right)=\\
&=\frac{1}{b^2}\left(\mathrm{E}\{Y^2\} - \mu_Y^2\right) = \frac{\sigma^2_Y}{b^2}.
\end{split}\end{equation*}

#### Inverse Transform

Now, if we want to do the inverse transform, for the mean, we have
\begin{equation*}
\mu_Y = b\cdot\mu_Z+a.
\end{equation*}
However, the standard deviation is independent of $a$, we have only the scale factor:
\begin{equation*}
\sigma_Y = b\cdot\sigma_Z.
\end{equation*}

#### Custom Scaler Implementation

```py
class MyScaler:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def fit(self, x):
        self.mu  = np.mean(x)
        self.std = np.std(x)

    def transform(self, x):
        return (x-self.mu)/self.std

    def inverse_transform_mean(self, x):
        '''To transform mean'''
        return x*self.std + self.mu

    def inverse_transform_std(self, x):
        '''To transform standard deviation'''
        return x*self.std
```

#### Scaler Usage

```py
y_scaler = MyScaler()
y_scaler.fit(Y_train)
Y_train_scale = y_scaler.transform(Y_train)

# Do your GPR fittting stuff here...
# Returns posterior mean Y_test
# and posterior standard deviation std

Y_test_real = y_scaler.inverse_transform_mean(Y_test)
std_real    = y_scaler.inverse_transform_std(std)
```

Comment: The 'MyScaler' is ideal for the use case here, if you change '$np.mean(x)$' and '$np.std(x)$' to '$np.mean(x,axis=0)$' and '$np.std(x,axis=0)$', it can be used to standardize data with more than one variable also